# Archlinux + intelgraphic + 2 monitors = crash system on login screen

Tags: archlinux, xorg

Intel Core i5-6600k The kernel parameters established `i915.preliminary_hw_support = 1` option for the new processors. When connected to a monitor, then everything is fine, but when I connect a second monitor to get the hang of the moment of transition to the login screen.
Sorry for my english. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You should file a bug against the Intel drivers. See https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/how-report-bugs for details.